# Absolute positioned image overflowing

Tags: html, css

I have a header section that should wrap according to the header image. Every page has a different image so it must be responsive. However header section will not wrap with the image since it is absolutely positioned.

As you can see in the snippet the image has `height: auto` on it and just overflows outside of the parent. Is there anyway to make the parent wrap according to the image?

```css
*, ::before, ::after {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
#header::before, #hero.background-wrapper::before {
    opacity: 0.2;
  }
  .background-wrapper::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  #hero {
    color: #fff;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    z-index: 1;
  }



  .hero-content {
    max-width: 911px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .hero-content {
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
  }

  .hero-text {
    margin-top: 100px;
    max-width: 750px;
  }

  .background-wrapper picture {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    inset: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    aspect-ratio: auto;
  }
  .background-wrapper picture img {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section id="hero" class="background-wrapper">
        <div class="container hero-content">
            <div class="hero-text">
                <h1>Header</h1>
                <h2>Header description</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <picture class="hero-picture"> 
            <source srcset="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/2011/07/img_8399.jpg.webp" media="(min-width: 600px)"> 
            <img src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/webp-express/webp-images/uploads/2011/07/img_8399-450x300.jpg.webp" alt="landing image" decoding="“async”"> 
        </picture>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please add a [example] and include some more details on what the desired result is.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely positioned elements are completely removed from the document flow, and thus their dimensions cannot alter the dimensions of their parents.

If you really had to achieve this affect while keeping the children as position: absolute, you could do so with JavaScript by finding the height of the absolutely positioned children after they have rendered, and using that to set the height of the parent.

Alternatively, just use `float: left`/`float:right` and margins to get the same positioning effect while keeping the children in the document flow, you can then use `overflow: hidden` on the parent (or any other clearfix technique) to cause its height to expand to that of its children.